# Python Tkでカスタムメッセージボックスを作りたい

Tags: python, python3, tkinter

Tkで準備されているmessageboxではなく、カスタムメッセージボックスを作りたいと考えています。

要件としては、

1. 常にTopLevelであること
   アプリケーションのコアとなるTkオブジェクトよりも、メッセージボックスが表示されている間は、メッセージボックスが前面にしたいです。
2. メッセージボックス以外の操作が不可（モーダル）
   メッセージボックスが押されるまで、他のTKオブジェクトは操作できないようにしたい。
3. メッセージボックスの戻り値を待つ
   メッセージボックスの入力を待ってから次のアクション（ウィジットの表示/非表示等）に移りたい。
4. アプリケーションの処理は継続したい
   アプリケーションのコアとなるTkオブジェクトは、afterメソッドにより定期的な処理は継続したい。
5. カスタムメッセージボックスには標準のタイトルバーはつけたくない。

このようなメッセージボックスをカスタムで作成したいのですが、うまくいきません。

**実行結果**
メッセージボックスは、モーダルにならず、閉じると以下のエラーになります。

```
invalid command name "1469565913800dialog_mouse_release"
    while executing
"1469565913800dialog_mouse_release 138 1 ?? ?? ?? 264 98160984 ?? 19 21 ?? 0 ?? ?? .!frame3.!button2 5 543 480 ??"
    invoked from within
"if {"[1469565913800dialog_mouse_release 138 1 ?? ?? ?? 264 98160984 ?? 19 21 ?? 0 ?? ?? .!frame3.!button2 5 543 480 ??]" == "break"} break"
    (command bound to event)
```

**ソースコード**

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

from tkinter import messagebox

from PIL import Image,ImageTk,ImageDraw,ImageFont

import datetime

class CustomDialog(object):
    def __init__(self):

        self.title_bar_color = '#8FAADC'
        self.item_ground_color = 'whitesmoke'
        self.background_color = '#D9D9D9'
        self.select_bar_color = '#BDD7EE'

        self.isDrag_DlgMotion = False
        self.drag_dx = 0
        self.drag_dy = 0
    
    def dialog_left_click(self,event):
        dialog_x=self.dev_dialog.winfo_rootx()
        dialog_y=self.dev_dialog.winfo_rooty()
        point_x=self.dev_dialog.winfo_pointerx()
        point_y=self.dev_dialog.winfo_pointery()

        dx = point_x - dialog_x
        dy = point_y - dialog_y

        if (dx >= 0 and dx <= self.title_bar_width) and (dy >= 0 and dy <= self.title_bar_height):
            self.drag_dx = dx
            self.drag_dy = dy
            self.isDrag_DlgMotion = True
        return

    def dialog_mouse_move_on(self,event):
        if self.isDrag_DlgMotion:
            X = event.x_root - self.drag_dx
            Y = event.y_root - self.drag_dy
            self.dev_dialog.geometry('+{0}+{1}'.format(X, Y))
            pass
        return

    def dialog_mouse_release(self,event):
        if self.isDrag_DlgMotion:
            self.isDrag_DlgMotion = False
        return

class CommonMessageBoxDialog(CustomDialog):
    def __init__(self,title,message,state,parent = None):
        self.return_state = None

        if not isinstance(title,str) or not isinstance(message,str) or not isinstance(state,int):
            return
        if state < 1 or state > 3 :
            return

        root = ttk.tkinter.Tk()

        #root = tk.Toplevel(parent)

        super().__init__()
        
        self.box_state = state
        self.box_message = message
        self.box_title = title

        W = 0
        H = 1

        self.dlg_size = [400,200]

        self.title_bar_width = self.dlg_size[W]
        self.title_bar_height = 40

        self.btn_bar_height = 42

        self.btn_32x32_size = 42

        self.row_height = 28
        self.btn_row_height = 32

        self.frm_space = 10

        self.parent = parent
        self.CreateDialog(root)

        root.mainloop()
    
    def CreateDialog(self,root):

        W = 0
        H = 1

        if self.parent != None:
            self.parent.update_idletasks()
            ww=self.parent.winfo_screenwidth()
            wh=self.parent.winfo_screenheight()
            x=self.parent.winfo_rootx()
            y=self.parent.winfo_rooty()

            parent_w = self.parent.winfo_width()
            parent_h = self.parent.winfo_height()
            parent_x = self.parent.winfo_x()
            parent_y = self.parent.winfo_y()
        else:
            root.update_idletasks()
            ww=root.winfo_screenwidth()
            wh=root.winfo_screenheight()
            x=root.winfo_rootx()
            y=root.winfo_rooty()

            parent_w = root.winfo_width()
            parent_h = root.winfo_height()
            parent_x = root.winfo_x()
            parent_y = root.winfo_y()


        self.dev_dialog = root
        dialog = self.dev_dialog
        dialog.overrideredirect(True)

        dlg_x = int((parent_x+parent_w) - (self.dlg_size[W]/2))
        dlg_y = int((parent_y+parent_h) - (self.dlg_size[H]/2))

        if dlg_x < 0 : dlg_x = 0 
        if dlg_y < 0 : dlg_y = 0 

        dialog.geometry('{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(self.dlg_size[W],self.dlg_size[H],dlg_x,dlg_y))


        self.Title_Bar = tk.Frame(
            dialog,            
            relief='flat',
            bg = self.title_bar_color ,
            )
        self.Title_Label = tk.Label(
            self.Title_Bar,
            bg = self.title_bar_color ,
            text = self.box_title,
        )

        dialog.bind('<Button-1>', self.dialog_left_click)
        dialog.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.dialog_mouse_move_on)
        dialog.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>',self.dialog_mouse_release)

        self.MsgArea_frame = tk.Frame(
            dialog,            
            relief='flat',
            bg = self.select_bar_color,
            )
        self.message_frame = tk.Frame(
            self.MsgArea_frame,
            relief='flat',
            bg = self.item_ground_color ,
            )
        self.label_message = tk.Label(
            self.message_frame,
            bg = self.item_ground_color ,
            text = self.box_message,
        )

        self.BtnArea_frame = tk.Frame(
            dialog,            
            relief='flat',
            bg = self.item_ground_color,
            )
            
        self.btn_ok = tk.Button(
            self.BtnArea_frame,            
            bg = self.item_ground_color,
            text = 'OK',
            command = lambda:self.btn_msgbox_clicked(1),
            )
            
        self.btn_yes = tk.Button(
            self.BtnArea_frame,            
            bg = self.item_ground_color,
            text = 'YES',
            command = lambda:self.btn_msgbox_clicked(1),
            )
            
        self.btn_no = tk.Button(
            self.BtnArea_frame,            
            bg = self.item_ground_color,
            text = 'NO',
            command = lambda:self.btn_msgbox_clicked(2),
            )
            
        self.btn_cancel = tk.Button(
            self.BtnArea_frame,            
            bg = self.item_ground_color,
            text = 'CANCEL',
            command = lambda:self.btn_msgbox_clicked(3),
            )
                
        frm_space = self.frm_space
        msg_frm_w = 4
        btn_fram_h = 36

        message_area_h = self.dlg_size[H] - self.title_bar_height - frm_space *2 - btn_fram_h

        # Frame
        self.Title_Bar.place(
            x = 0, y = 0, 
            width = self.title_bar_width, height = self.title_bar_height
            )
        self.MsgArea_frame.place(
            x = frm_space, y = self.title_bar_height + frm_space, 
            width = self.title_bar_width - frm_space*2, height = message_area_h
            )
        self.BtnArea_frame.place(
            x = 0, y = self.title_bar_height + frm_space + message_area_h, 
            width = self.title_bar_width, height = btn_fram_h
            )
        
        self.Title_Label.grid(row = 0, column = 1,sticky = tk.W+tk.N+tk.S)
        self.Title_Bar.columnconfigure(0,minsize = self.frm_space)
        self.Title_Bar.rowconfigure(0,minsize = self.title_bar_height)
        
        self.MsgArea_frame.columnconfigure(0,minsize = self.frm_space)
        self.MsgArea_frame.rowconfigure(0,minsize = message_area_h)
        
        self.BtnArea_frame.rowconfigure(0,minsize = btn_fram_h)

        self.message_frame.place(
            x = msg_frm_w, y = msg_frm_w,
            width = self.title_bar_width - frm_space*2 - msg_frm_w*2, height = message_area_h - msg_frm_w*2,
            )

        # self.message_frame
        self.label_message.grid(row = 0, column = 1,sticky = tk.W+tk.N+tk.S)

        if self.box_state == 1:
            self.btn_ok.place(
                x = (self.title_bar_width/2) - 80/2 , y = btn_fram_h/2 - 24/2,
                )            
        if self.box_state == 2:
            self.btn_yes.place(
                x = (self.title_bar_width/2) - (80 + frm_space) , y = btn_fram_h/2 - 24/2,
                )            
            self.btn_no.place(
                x = (self.title_bar_width/2) + frm_space , y = btn_fram_h/2 - 24/2,
                )            
        if self.box_state == 3:
            self.btn_yes.place(
                x = (self.title_bar_width/2) - (80*1.5 + frm_space*2) , y = btn_fram_h/2 - 24/2,
                )            
            self.btn_no.place(
                x = (self.title_bar_width/2) - 80/2 , y = btn_fram_h/2 - 24/2,
                )            
            self.btn_cancel.place(
                x = (self.title_bar_width/2) + 80/2 + frm_space*2 , y = btn_fram_h/2 - 24/2,
                )
            
        dialog.grab_set_global()

    def btn_msgbox_clicked(self,state):
        self.return_state = state
        self.dev_dialog.destroy()

    def get_return_state(self):
        return self.return_state

class CreateScreen(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cnt = 0
        W = 0
        H = 1
        self.dlg_size = [400,200]

        geo_string = '{}x{}'.format(self.dlg_size[W],self.dlg_size[H])

        self.MainWindow_obj = ttk.tkinter.Tk()
        self.MainWindow_obj.geometry(geo_string) 

        self.CntSting = tk.StringVar()
        self.CntSting.set('...')

        Label_Conter_text = tk.Label(
            self.MainWindow_obj,
            textvariable = self.CntSting,
        )

        self.MsgSting = tk.StringVar()
        self.MsgSting.set(str(self.cnt))

        Label_Message_text = tk.Label(
            self.MainWindow_obj,
            textvariable = self.MsgSting,
        )

        Btn_Messagebox = tk.Button(
            self.MainWindow_obj,
            text = 'Push',
            command = self.Btn_Messagebox_clicked
        )
        Label_Conter_text.pack()
        Label_Message_text.pack()
        Btn_Messagebox.pack()

        self.MainWindow_obj.after(1000,self.loop_msg)

        self.MainWindow_obj.mainloop()

    def Btn_Messagebox_clicked(self):
        self.dlg = CommonMessageBoxDialog(title='Test',message='Do you remember ?',state=3,parent =self.MainWindow_obj)        
        ret = self.dlg.get_return_state()

        if ret == 1:
            self.MsgSting.set('Yes')
        if ret == 2:
            self.MsgSting.set('No')
        if ret == 3:
            self.MsgSting.set('Cancel')
        
        return

    def loop_msg(self):
        self.cnt += 1
        self.MsgSting.set(str(self.cnt))

        self.MainWindow_obj.after(1000,self.loop_msg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    screen_obj = CreateScreen()
```

Comment: これが少し参考になるかも。[【Python GUI tkinterサンプル】Tkinter　TopLevelを使ってmodaldialog(モーダルなダイアログ)を実装する](https://suzutaka-programming.com/tkinter-modaldialog/), [How to create a modal dialog in tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16803686/9014308)

Comment: grab_set_globalにより、モーダルにすることができました。
しかし、エラー表示は解消できませんでした。Btn_Messagebox_clickedメソッドの2行目の処理は、メインウィンドウを閉じるまで実行されないことが分かりました。main_loopメソッドから戻ってこないようです。

Comment: これらの記事 [Correct way to implement a custom popup tkinter dialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10057672/9014308), [Dialog Windows](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm) にそれに関連するらしき記述がありそうです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

どうやら自己解決できたようです。
エラーのメッセージdialog_mouse_releaseから、マウスのリリースイベントを通知したいのに、ダイアログが破棄されてしまっていることが原因と推定しました。

CreateDialogメソッドにおいて、Button-1、B1-Motion、ButtonRelease-1をバインドしています。これは、タイトルバーに代えてself.Title_Barをドラッグするとボックスを移動させるためにバインドしています。

そこで、
btn_msgbox_clickedメソッドにおいては、フラグ変数：self.isDestroyを用いて、
その後にバインドされたdialog_mouse_releaseメソッドが呼び出されるので、そこからdestroyメソッドを呼ぶように変更しました。

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

from tkinter import messagebox

from PIL import Image,ImageTk,ImageDraw,ImageFont

import datetime

class CustomDialog(object):
    def __init__(self):

        self.title_bar_color = '#8FAADC'
        self.item_ground_color = 'whitesmoke'
        self.background_color = '#D9D9D9'
        self.select_bar_color = '#BDD7EE'

        self.isDrag_DlgMotion = False
        self.drag_dx = 0
        self.drag_dy = 0

    def dialog_left_click(self,event):
        dialog_x=self.dev_dialog.winfo_rootx()
        dialog_y=self.dev_dialog.winfo_rooty()
        point_x=self.dev_dialog.winfo_pointerx()
        point_y=self.dev_dialog.winfo_pointery()

        dx = point_x - dialog_x
        dy = point_y - dialog_y

        if (dx >= 0 and dx <= self.title_bar_width) and (dy >= 0 and dy <= self.title_bar_height):
            self.drag_dx = dx
            self.drag_dy = dy
            self.isDrag_DlgMotion = True
        return

    def dialog_mouse_move_on(self,event):
        if self.isDrag_DlgMotion:
            X = event.x_root - self.drag_dx
            Y = event.y_root - self.drag_dy
            self.dev_dialog.geometry('+{0}+{1}'.format(X, Y))
            pass
        return

    def dialog_mouse_release(self,event):
        if self.isDrag_DlgMotion:
            self.isDrag_DlgMotion = False
        return

class CommonMessageBoxDialog(CustomDialog):
    def __init__(self,title,message,state,parent = None):
        self.return_state = None
        self.isDestroy = False

        if not isinstance(title,str) or not isinstance(message,str) or not isinstance(state,int):
            return
        if state < 1 or state > 3 :
            return

        root = ttk.tkinter.Tk()

        #root = tk.Toplevel(parent)
        #root.overrideredirect(True)

        super().__init__()

        self.box_state = state
        self.box_message = message
        self.box_title = title

        W = 0
        H = 1

        self.dlg_size = [400,200]

        self.title_bar_width = self.dlg_size[W]
        self.title_bar_height = 40

        self.btn_bar_height = 42

        self.btn_32x32_size = 42

        self.row_height = 28
        self.btn_row_height = 32

        self.frm_space = 10

        self.parent = parent
        self.CreateDialog(root)

        root.wait_window(root)

        #root.mainloop()

    def CreateDialog(self,root):

        W = 0
        H = 1

        if self.parent != None:
            self.parent.update_idletasks()
            ww=self.parent.winfo_screenwidth()
            wh=self.parent.winfo_screenheight()
            x=self.parent.winfo_rootx()
            y=self.parent.winfo_rooty()

            parent_w = self.parent.winfo_width()
            parent_h = self.parent.winfo_height()
            parent_x = self.parent.winfo_x()
            parent_y = self.parent.winfo_y()
        else:
            root.update_idletasks()
            ww=root.winfo_screenwidth()
            wh=root.winfo_screenheight()
            x=root.winfo_rootx()
            y=root.winfo_rooty()

            parent_w = root.winfo_width()
            parent_h = root.winfo_height()
            parent_x = root.winfo_x()
            parent_y = root.winfo_y()


        self.dev_dialog = root
        dialog = self.dev_dialog
        dialog.overrideredirect(True)

        dlg_x = int((parent_x+parent_w) - (self.dlg_size[W]/2))
        dlg_y = int((parent_y+parent_h) - (self.dlg_size[H]/2))

        if dlg_x < 0 : dlg_x = 0 
        if dlg_y < 0 : dlg_y = 0 

        dialog.geometry('{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(self.dlg_size[W],self.dlg_size[H],dlg_x,dlg_y))


        self.Title_Bar = tk.Frame(
            dialog,            
            relief='flat',
            bg = self.title_bar_color ,
            )
        self.Title_Label = tk.Label(
            self.Title_Bar,
            bg = self.title_bar_color ,
            text = self.box_title,
        )

        dialog.bind('<Button-1>', self.dialog_left_click)
        dialog.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.dialog_mouse_move_on)
        dialog.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>',self.dialog_mouse_release)

        self.MsgArea_frame = tk.Frame(
            dialog,            
            relief='flat',
            bg = self.select_bar_color,
            )
        self.message_frame = tk.Frame(
            self.MsgArea_frame,
            relief='flat',
            bg = self.item_ground_color ,
            )
        self.label_message = tk.Label(
            self.message_frame,
            bg = self.item_ground_color ,
            text = self.box_message,
        )

        self.BtnArea_frame = tk.Frame(
            dialog,            
            relief='flat',
            bg = self.item_ground_color,
            )

        self.btn_ok = tk.Button(
            self.BtnArea_frame,            
            bg = self.item_ground_color,
            text = 'OK',
            command = lambda:self.btn_msgbox_clicked(1),
            )

        self.btn_yes = tk.Button(
            self.BtnArea_frame,            
            bg = self.item_ground_color,
            text = 'YES',
            command = lambda:self.btn_msgbox_clicked(1),
            )

        self.btn_no = tk.Button(
            self.BtnArea_frame,            
            bg = self.item_ground_color,
            text = 'NO',
            command = lambda:self.btn_msgbox_clicked(2),
            )

        self.btn_cancel = tk.Button(
            self.BtnArea_frame,            
            bg = self.item_ground_color,
            text = 'CANCEL',
            command = lambda:self.btn_msgbox_clicked(3),
            )

        frm_space = self.frm_space
        msg_frm_w = 4
        btn_fram_h = 36

        message_area_h = self.dlg_size[H] - self.title_bar_height - frm_space *2 - btn_fram_h

        # Frame
        self.Title_Bar.place(
            x = 0, y = 0, 
            width = self.title_bar_width, height = self.title_bar_height
            )
        self.MsgArea_frame.place(
            x = frm_space, y = self.title_bar_height + frm_space, 
            width = self.title_bar_width - frm_space*2, height = message_area_h
            )
        self.BtnArea_frame.place(
            x = 0, y = self.title_bar_height + frm_space + message_area_h, 
            width = self.title_bar_width, height = btn_fram_h
            )

        self.Title_Label.grid(row = 0, column = 1,sticky = tk.W+tk.N+tk.S)
        self.Title_Bar.columnconfigure(0,minsize = self.frm_space)
        self.Title_Bar.rowconfigure(0,minsize = self.title_bar_height)

        self.MsgArea_frame.columnconfigure(0,minsize = self.frm_space)
        self.MsgArea_frame.rowconfigure(0,minsize = message_area_h)

        self.BtnArea_frame.rowconfigure(0,minsize = btn_fram_h)

        self.message_frame.place(
            x = msg_frm_w, y = msg_frm_w,
            width = self.title_bar_width - frm_space*2 - msg_frm_w*2, height = message_area_h - msg_frm_w*2,
            )

        # self.message_frame
        self.label_message.grid(row = 0, column = 1,sticky = tk.W+tk.N+tk.S)

        if self.box_state == 1:
            self.btn_ok.place(
                x = (self.title_bar_width/2) - 80/2 , y = btn_fram_h/2 - 24/2,
                )            
        if self.box_state == 2:
            self.btn_yes.place(
                x = (self.title_bar_width/2) - (80 + frm_space) , y = btn_fram_h/2 - 24/2,
                )            
            self.btn_no.place(
                x = (self.title_bar_width/2) + frm_space , y = btn_fram_h/2 - 24/2,
                )            
        if self.box_state == 3:
            self.btn_yes.place(
                x = (self.title_bar_width/2) - (80*1.5 + frm_space*2) , y = btn_fram_h/2 - 24/2,
                )            
            self.btn_no.place(
                x = (self.title_bar_width/2) - 80/2 , y = btn_fram_h/2 - 24/2,
                )            
            self.btn_cancel.place(
                x = (self.title_bar_width/2) + 80/2 + frm_space*2 , y = btn_fram_h/2 - 24/2,
                )            

        #dialog.grab_set()
        dialog.grab_set_global()

    def btn_msgbox_clicked(self,state):
        self.return_state = state
        self.isDestroy = True

    def get_return_state(self):
        return self.return_state

    def dialog_mouse_release(self,event):
        if self.isDrag_DlgMotion:
            self.isDrag_DlgMotion = False

        if self.isDestroy:
            self._quit()
        return

    def _quit(self):
        self.dev_dialog.grab_release()
        self.dev_dialog.destroy()


class CreateScreen(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cnt = 0
        W = 0
        H = 1
        self.dlg_size = [400,200]

        geo_string = '{}x{}'.format(self.dlg_size[W],self.dlg_size[H])

        self.MainWindow_obj = ttk.tkinter.Tk()
        self.MainWindow_obj.geometry(geo_string) 

        self.CntSting = tk.StringVar()
        self.CntSting.set(str(self.cnt))

        Label_Conter_text = tk.Label(
            self.MainWindow_obj,
            textvariable = self.CntSting,
        )

        self.MsgSting = tk.StringVar()
        self.MsgSting.set('...')

        Label_Message_text = tk.Label(
            self.MainWindow_obj,
            textvariable = self.MsgSting,
        )

        Btn_Messagebox = tk.Button(
            self.MainWindow_obj,
            text = 'Push',
            command = self.Btn_Messagebox_clicked
        )
        Label_Conter_text.pack()
        Label_Message_text.pack()
        Btn_Messagebox.pack()

        self.MainWindow_obj.after(1000,self.loop_msg)

        self.MainWindow_obj.mainloop()

    def Btn_Messagebox_clicked(self):
        self.dlg = CommonMessageBoxDialog(title='Test',message='Do you remember ?',state=3,parent =self.MainWindow_obj)        
        ret = self.dlg.get_return_state()

        if ret == 1:
            self.MsgSting.set('Yes')
        if ret == 2:
            self.MsgSting.set('No')
        if ret == 3:
            self.MsgSting.set('Cancel')

        return

    def loop_msg(self):
        self.cnt += 1
        self.CntSting.set(str(self.cnt))

        self.MainWindow_obj.after(1000,self.loop_msg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    screen_obj = CreateScreen()
```